# Cannot convert pass created from walletpass api to data

Tags: node.js, swift, wallet, passkit, pkpass

So here is what I got: I created two certificates both a signerCertificate and a signerKey and converted them to .pem files. They work, and I am able to sign the pass in the console on my Mac terminal to create a pkpass. So the certificates work and I need to add this to my app and edit some of the fields in the pass so I decided to use https://github.com/walletpass/pass-js to setup my backend certificate signage. So I implemented all of the necessary documentation steps and before you know it, I could create what I think is a pass bc it prints in our console logs as seen in below code.

So here is where the problem starts. I am trying to return the pass data to the front end as seen below. It does not cast as Data or NSData no matter what variation I return from their documentation on the front end. So what is my goal? I have generated the pass template and it returns some sort of pass data, but Im stuck trying to cast it as data in the front end to make it into a pkpass that I can open for users in the app! Me and my coworker have tried everything we can to figure this out but we are at a dead end.

If you have any advice please leave it below. Please see all the attached screenshots and code below as well.

**NODE JS Api Call**

```
 const { Template } = require("@walletpass/pass-js");   
exports.createTicket = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    
      const key = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----MIIF/jCCBOagaeYE=-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
      const template = new Template("eventTicket", {
      passTypeIdentifier: "pass.com.passllc.eventCard",
      teamIdentifier: "ABCDEFGHI",
      organizationName : "Scenes",
      backgroundColor: "red",
      sharingProhibited: true
    });
      await template.images.add("icon", "./models/icon.png");
      await template.images.add("logo", "./models/logo.png");
      template.setCertificate(key);
      template.setPrivateKey("-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----MIIFDj0I=-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----", "passphrase");
      const pass = template.createPass({
      serialNumber: "123456",
      description: "20% off"
      });
      console.log(pass);
      return {
              status: '200',
              type: "application/vnd.apple.pkpass",
              body: await pass.asBuffer(),
        };
     });
```

**Front End Code**

```
functions.httpsCallable("createTicket").call(["test": "dummytext"]) { (result, error) in
            if let data = result?.data as? [String: Any] {
                let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data)
                do {
                 var passError: NSError?
                 var newPass = try PKPass(data: jsonData as! Data, error: &passError)
                    print("pkpassage: \(newPass)")
                    let addController = PKAddPassesViewController(pass: newPass)
                         addController.delegate = self
                    self.present(addController, animated: true)
                } catch {
                }
            }
            if (error as NSError?) != nil {
                print("\(error?.localizedDescription) lower error")
            }
        }
```

**What is currently outputting**

Front end console (Xcode)
[errorOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLbFT.png)

Backend Console (Server logs) just a small snippet of the whole log for an individual call
[console server log beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCOma.png);
[console server log end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wSQf.png)

I also tried both of these cases btw and they still cannot convert to something to cast as a pkpass:
[creating the file for api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1WYb.png)

I would also like to add when I print the returned pass in front end Xcode console as string: any it prints something like [234434, 45549, 3828].
As you can see it looks like a pass is generating because the console is logging it, just I cant get it to convert into data that I can convert to a pkpass. I really appreciate any help, thank you guys!

Comment: Take a raw .pkpass bundle and try and open it on a Mac.  If there is anything wrong with the bundle, the console log will tell you.  In Xcode, a possible reason for the nil value is that there is something wrong with your pass bundle.